# Can I control/read an RFID reader with an Android device or do I have to put an Arduino board between the two?

Tags: arduino, rfid, android

I want to develop and Android app the reads RFID tags. I am wondering if I can control the RFID reader directly with an Android device or do I have to put an Arduino board between the two. The RFID reader I have is called the Cottonwood. Here's a picture of it:

[image: cottonwood]

I think these are the commands you can send it:

https://s3.amazonaws.com/linksprite/RFID/integrated+reader/UHF_RFID_integrated_protocol.pdf

Here's a quick start guide:

http://learn.linksprite.com/rfid/cottonwood-uhf-long-distance-rfid-reader-module-quick-start-guide/

Comment: what does the data sheet say about connectivity to the device?

Comment: probably USB, but the datasheet says next to nothing about timing diagrams

Comment: i put a quick start guide link in the post. it looks like it says you can connect to a PC with UART-USB or mini USB and then under `3. Read Tag` there's a bunch of desktop screenshots of settings/commands. can i run those commands if an android device it connected directly to it. would i have to use the android ndk(C/C++) or could i use Java?

Comment: First plug it into a Linux PC and see what it is detected as, hopefully a recognized USB serial device, figure out which one from `dmesg` or by reading the chip markings.  Android's USB host APIs are ordinary Java APIs rather than NDK.  Note however that this can of approach can be troublesome - both power concerns and general flakiness may challenge keeping it running.

Answer (score 1):

Android devices can usually connect directly to USB devices in OTG mode. It looks like that board has a USB serial interface, so it should work fine if you connect it with the proper USB OTG cable.

Now, how you actually talk to it is a different story. I'm far from an expert on Android, but a quick Google search turned up https://github.com/mik3y/usb-serial-for-android which may do what you need.